# Lotus script Lockout users how to get list of useres in memo

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus

```
    Sub Initialize

On Error GoTo e
Dim session As New NotesSession, db As NotesDatabase, view As NotesView
Dim nvec As NotesViewEntryCollection
Dim c As integer
Set db = session.currentdatabase

Set view = db.getView("Locked Out Users")
Set nvec = view.Allentries

c = nvec.count

If c > 0 Then

Call nvec.Removeall(true)

' Send notification
Dim sarr(1) As String
sarr(0) = "john.doe@acme.com"
sarr(1) = "foo@acme.com"

Dim mdoc As NotesDocument, rt As notesrichtextitem
Set mdoc = db.createdocument
mdoc.Form = "Memo"
mdoc.Subject = "Removed " + CStr(c) + " Locked out users on mypage"
Set rt = mdoc.Createrichtextitem("Body")
Call rt.Appendtext("Removed " + CStr(c) + " Locked out users")
Call rt.Addnewline(1) 
Call rt.Appendtext("Click to open lockout database")
Call rt.Appenddoclink(db,"Lockout")
Call mdoc.Send(False, sarr)

End If
Exit Sub
e:
Print Error,erl
End Sub
```

It's possible to get list of users who locked in memo (e-mail)? maybe there is a method to display and send this type of view in lotusscript?

It try

```
Dim item As NotesItem
```

Set item = doc.getItemValue("ILUserName")

each time he receives only their number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the nvec.Removeall to the end of your code as it deletes all locked out users.

Then initialize your richtext and cycle through the collection and put each name in the richtext like that:

```
Dim ve as NotesViewEntry
Dim doc as NotesDocument

…

Call rt.Appendtext("Removed " + CStr(c) + " Locked out users")
Call rt.Addnewline(1)
Call rt.Appendtext("Removed the following users:")
Call rt.Addnewline(1)
view.AutoUpdate = False 'necessary in case a user is locked while the code runs then your reference migth become broken...
Set ve = nvec.GetFirstEntry()
While not ve is Nothing
  If ve.IsDocument then
    Set doc = ve.Document
    Call rt.AppendText( doc.IlUserName(0) )
    Call rt.Addnewline(1)
  End If
  Set ve = nvec.GetNextEntry( ve )
Wend
Call nvec.RemoveAll(True)
…
' the rest code with the database link comes here.
```